# Symfony2 , add attr "for" for label

Tags: symfony, theming

I'd like to know how to add attr **"for"** for labels and put the name of input as value  of attr for

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_label %}
    <label class="control-label" for="">
        {{ label }}
    </label>

{% endblock %}


{% block form_widget_simple %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form) }}

        {{ parent() }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Solved**

I have removed the first block {% block form_label %}

Answer (score 0):

In **twig**:

```
{{ form_label(form.something, null, {'label_attr': {'for': 'your-value'}}) }}
```

In **form builder**:

```
$builder->add('something', null, array(
    'label_attr' => array('for' => 'your-value')
));
```